# Dlink wireless adapter dwa 125 on ubuntu 11.04

Tags: wireless, internet

I am new to linux, bought a desktop computer a couple of days ago with linux ubuntu 11.04 installed on it. I think its wonderful, i have one issue however. i need an "in laments terms" step-by-step way to configure my Dlink dwa 125 N 150 to work wirelessly. I feel as though ive tried every forum, and guide, ive even spoken to a tech savvy friend and nothing seems to be working. ive installed the driver properly albeit i have no way of seeing installed properly (im new) If someone could please please help me as soon as possible that would be awesome. Thanks!

Sara

Answer (score 1):

(EN)

I could install my N150 Wireless Desktop PCI Adapter on Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick" and I have recently installed the 12.04 version "Precise" (works with all)

- You must have installers card CD or downloaded from the website of D-link (DWA-525)

STEPS

- First remove the card from the port.
- Install "ndiswrapper" and "ndisgtk" from Software Center

or search the packages

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

When "ndiswrapper" and "ndisgtk" were installed the application creates the application "Drivers for Windows wireless networks".

- Go to System> Administration> Drivers for Windows wireless networks
- You go and look for the *. Inf in the drivers (DWA-525 folder) and voila, It worked to me with WinXP driver
- Turn off the PC
- Place the card into the PCI slot and turn on .....
- automatically recognizes you.

:)

/////////////////////////////end ///////////////////

(ES)

Pude instalar mi N150 Wireless Desktop PCI Adapter en Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick", y hace poco he instalado la versión 12.04 "Preciso" (funciona con todos)

- Debe tener los instaladores de CD tarjeta o descargado desde la página web de D-Link (DWA-525)

PASOS

- En primer lugar retire la tarjeta desde el puerto.
- Instalar "ndiswrapper" y "ndisgtk" del Centro de Software

o buscar en los paquetes

http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/i386/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

Cuando el "ndiswrapper" y "ndisgtk" se ha instalado la aplicación crea la aplicación "Controladores para redes inalámbricas de Windows".

- Vaya a Sistema> Administración> Controladores para redes inalámbricas de Windows
- Ve y busca el archivo *. Inf. en los conductores (DWA-525 carpeta) y voilá, funcionó a mí con driver para Windows XP
- Apague el PC
- Coloque la tarjeta en la ranura PCI y encender .....
- Automáticamente reconoce.

:)